# PunchJs Edit for No vertical Move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to edit PUNCH.js so that the drag will only be left-right

i.e remove vertical movement.

Does anybody see a way to do this with Punch.js

Or how would i limit the vertical movement within a div but using punch.

Here is the PUNCH CODE.

Thanks for any help.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this myself. so any help would be seriously appreciated.

Many thanks again

Mel.

```
/*!
 * jQuery UI Touch Punch 0.2.3
 *
 * Copyright 2011–2014, Dave Furfero
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 *
 * Depends:
 *  jquery.ui.widget.js
 *  jquery.ui.mouse.js
 */
(function ($) {

  // Detect touch support
  $.support.touch = 'ontouchend' in document;

  // Ignore browsers without touch support
  if (!$.support.touch) {
    return;
  }

  var mouseProto = $.ui.mouse.prototype,
      _mouseInit = mouseProto._mouseInit,
      _mouseDestroy = mouseProto._mouseDestroy,
      touchHandled;

  /**
   * Simulate a mouse event based on a corresponding touch event
   * @param {Object} event A touch event
   * @param {String} simulatedType The corresponding mouse event
   */
  function simulateMouseEvent (event, simulatedType) {

    // Ignore multi-touch events
    if (event.originalEvent.touches.length > 1) {
      return;
    }

    event.preventDefault();

    var touch = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0],
        simulatedEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');

    // Initialize the simulated mouse event using the touch event's coordinates
    simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(
      simulatedType,    // type
      true,             // bubbles                    
      true,             // cancelable                 
      window,           // view                       
      1,                // detail                     
      touch.screenX,    // screenX                    
      touch.screenY,    // screenY                    
      touch.clientX,    // clientX                    
      touch.clientY,    // clientY                    
      false,            // ctrlKey                    
      false,            // altKey                     
      false,            // shiftKey                   
      false,            // metaKey                    
      0,                // button                     
      null              // relatedTarget              
    );

    // Dispatch the simulated event to the target element
    event.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
  }

  /**
   * Handle the jQuery UI widget's touchstart events
   * @param {Object} event The widget element's touchstart event
   */
  mouseProto._touchStart = function (event) {

    var self = this;

    // Ignore the event if another widget is already being handled
    if (touchHandled || !self._mouseCapture(event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0])) {
      return;
    }

    // Set the flag to prevent other widgets from inheriting the touch event
    touchHandled = true;

    // Track movement to determine if interaction was a click
    self._touchMoved = false;

    // Simulate the mouseover event
    simulateMouseEvent(event, 'mouseover');

    // Simulate the mousemove event
    simulateMouseEvent(event, 'mousemove');

    // Simulate the mousedown event
    simulateMouseEvent(event, 'mousedown');
  };

  /**
   * Handle the jQuery UI widget's touchmove events
   * @param {Object} event The document's touchmove event
   */
  mouseProto._touchMove = function (event) {

    // Ignore event if not handled
    if (!touchHandled) {
      return;
    }

    // Interaction was not a click
    this._touchMoved = true;

    // Simulate the mousemove event
    simulateMouseEvent(event, 'mousemove');
  };

  /**
   * Handle the jQuery UI widget's touchend events
   * @param {Object} event The document's touchend event
   */
  mouseProto._touchEnd = function (event) {

    // Ignore event if not handled
    if (!touchHandled) {
      return;
    }

    // Simulate the mouseup event
    simulateMouseEvent(event, 'mouseup');

    // Simulate the mouseout event
    simulateMouseEvent(event, 'mouseout');

    // If the touch interaction did not move, it should trigger a click
    if (!this._touchMoved) {

      // Simulate the click event
      simulateMouseEvent(event, 'click');
    }

    // Unset the flag to allow other widgets to inherit the touch event
    touchHandled = false;
  };

  /**
   * A duck punch of the $.ui.mouse _mouseInit method to support touch events.
   * This method extends the widget with bound touch event handlers that
   * translate touch events to mouse events and pass them to the widget's
   * original mouse event handling methods.
   */
  mouseProto._mouseInit = function () {

    var self = this;

    // Delegate the touch handlers to the widget's element
    self.element.bind({
      touchstart: $.proxy(self, '_touchStart'),
      touchmove: $.proxy(self, '_touchMove'),
      touchend: $.proxy(self, '_touchEnd')
    });

    // Call the original $.ui.mouse init method
    _mouseInit.call(self);
  };

  /**
   * Remove the touch event handlers
   */
  mouseProto._mouseDestroy = function () {

    var self = this;

    // Delegate the touch handlers to the widget's element
    self.element.unbind({
      touchstart: $.proxy(self, '_touchStart'),
      touchmove: $.proxy(self, '_touchMove'),
      touchend: $.proxy(self, '_touchEnd')
    });

    // Call the original $.ui.mouse destroy method
    _mouseDestroy.call(self);
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: jQuery Touch Punch doesn't handle the actual movement. All it does is simulate mouse events based on touch events. _jquery.ui.mouse.js_ is probably the one that handles the actual movement. Though perhaps you could simply remove `touch.screenY,` and `touch.clientY,` to get what you want. It would only work for people using touch screens though. It wouldn't affect users that use a mouse.

Comment: ok, il try to remove them. iv allready got a mouse events setup, so thats not the problem, the problem was i couldnt get a touch slider event working, and using punch at the moment seems to be me only oprion...allthough im now trying to use SLICK.js , but i get .slickPlay is not a function!

Comment: If you have a new question, create a new one. Don't continue asking new questions on an old question as it's very confusing and doesn't help anyone that might have the same question in the future. I can't help you with the information you provided in that comment anyway. There can be any number of reasons why you get that error and without seeing your code it'll be impossible to know what it is.

Comment: Ok thanks for that.